# Solving a non linear second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I go about solving a **nonlinear** ordinary equation that is of **second** order?

Such as 
$$y'' + ay^3 = 0$$ 
where $a$ is a constant.

Comment: your equation is not solvable in the known elementary functions

Comment: Write the equation as $y'' = -ay^3$, and then multiply by $y'$ to get $y''*y' = -ay^3*y'$.  Integrating that should give you form you recognize.

Comment: I got to y = +-i * sqrt(a/2) * 1/x, is this correct ? I would like to get a physical interpreation as well, as this equation arised from physics.

Comment: After we integrate, we should have $\frac{1}{2} (y')^2 + c_1 = \frac{-a}{4} y^4$.  You'll find that we can solve for $x$, not $y$ (in elementary functions.  Try to finish my computation.

Comment: Try http://dlmf.nist.gov/22.19#ii

Answer (score 1):

$$y'' + ay^3 = 0\\
y'y'' + ay'y^3 = 0
$$
Now integrate to get
$$
\frac13 y'^2  =  - \frac a4y^4 + C
$$
Write $C$ in a way such as
$$
y'^2  =   \frac 34a(y_0^4 - y^4)\\
dy = \pm \sqrt{\frac 34a(y_0^4 - y^4)} dt\\
t  = \int \frac{dy} {\sqrt{\frac 34a(y_0^4 - y^4)} }
= \frac2{\sqrt{3a}}  \frac{\log\frac{y_0 + y}{y_0 - y} + 2\arctan \frac y{y_0}}{4y_0^3} + const.
$$